# How could I prove that every interval in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am having serious trouble on giving a general argument in order to prove this. If someone could give me some advice, or some little hint, on how to do it... or some bibliography where I can find a complete proof... Thanks in advance so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how can you prove it in an example on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose your interval is
$$I=(a,b] \times [c,d] \times (e,f)$$
then lets work every interval on its own.

For the $G_\delta$ case we have that
$$(a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a, b+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$[c,d]= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(c-\dfrac{1}{n}, d+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$
so
\begin{align*}
I & =\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a, b+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \times \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(c-\dfrac{1}{n}, d+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \times (e,f)=\\
 & = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \left(a, b+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \times\left(c-\dfrac{1}{n}, d+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \times (e,f)\right]
\end{align*}

Now, for the $F_\sigma$ case, we have that
$$(a,b]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[a+\dfrac{1}{n}, b  \right]$$
$$(e,f)=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left[e+\dfrac{1}{m}, f-\dfrac{1}{m} \right]$$
so
\begin{align*}
I & =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[a+\dfrac{1}{n}, b  \right] \times [c,d] \times \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left[e+\dfrac{1}{n}, f-\dfrac{1}{n} \right]\\
 & = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left( \left[a+\dfrac{1}{n}, b  \right] \times [c,d] \times \left[e+\dfrac{1}{m}, f-\dfrac{1}{m} \right] \right)
\end{align*}

Observe that, for the $F_\sigma$ case we have to consider distinct subindices in the unions to make sure the last equality holds but we still have a numerable union of closed sets so it is an $F_\sigma$.

The generalization to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is immediaty following this example.

Comment: thank you so much for this clarifying answer!